# How to Configure Laravel with Jetstream, Inertia, Svelte (Front-end) and Vue (Admin Dashboard)?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, svelte, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I am fairly new to Laravel, Jetstream, Inertia, Svelte, and Vue. I am currently working on a project where I'd like to use Laravel with Jetstream and Inertia, but my aim is to use Svelte for the front-end and Vue as the default for the admin dashboard. While I can get everything running standalone, i.e., Laravel with Inertia and Svelte and Laravel with Inertia and Jetstream with Vue, I am encountering difficulties when attempting to combine them.

I want to set up the routes in such a way that Svelte is used for all routes except the '/admin' route, which should use Vue as provided by Jetstream. I attempted to use a conditional statement (`if ( ... )`) in the `createInertiaApp` method based on URL parameters to switch between Vue and Svelte, but it did not yield the expected results. I am not certain if `app.js` runs on every page render.

So far, I have not been able to find any resources or related questions that provide a clear answer to this. I only found ways to do a or b, not both.

Given this, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to configure Laravel with Jetstream, Inertia, Svelte, and Vue in the manner described above?
2. If so, what steps should I follow to correctly set this up?
3. If not, is there an alternative way to achieve similar functionality or is it not worth the trouble?

I appreciate any advice or insights you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do think that it's possible to have 2 frontend framework to work with inertia.js

I never tried this myself, but maybe you can change app.js to `vue.js` and `svelte.js` to run both `createInertiaApp`  for vue and svelte. You can do this by splitting both vue and svelte to 2 different files and call it from `app.js`

Now, your `vite.config.js` file should accept both Vue and Inertia.js by importing both plugins to vite config.

Lastly, you can make 2 layout files, each to be the main layout file for each framework.

`vue.blade.php` should have this in the head:

```
@vite('resources/js/vue.js')
```

and your `vite.config.js` should accept it:

```
laravel({
     input: ["resources/js/vue.js"],
     refresh: true,
}),
```

That's the gist of it, it may not run correctly, but i guess it's the baseline of it